# C# why throw errors

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, throw

Im not getting the `throw` keyword, why use it? What are the benefits of it?

As of now I've got this in my UI class:

```
try
{
  Classreference.MethodToRun();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

This works but I guess with `throw` I could make the method I am calling throw the error instead and catch it in my UI class? But why? What is better about it? Is it done to make the classes more object oriented or what? I am guessing if I just catch the error in my UI class I wont need to change the code if I change the method I am calling, but instead change the error message in the method being changed?

Comment: Google "C# exception handling best practices" and read every article you possibly can.

Comment: Gah! Stop the close fest madness people! This is a real question... with some code in it. There are real useful answers here.

Comment: @Josh - look at the edit history. The question was incomprehensible to begin with.

Comment: @Oded - So add a comment asking for more info, or clarity. Give the asker a *freakin chance* to at least conform to the standards before you go close the question. The 1st maxim of SO should be to help people. Making sure the content is high quality is a distant second.

Comment: Well excuse me for offending you by asking a question you didnt understand then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use throw to indicate that an error has occured or to pass an existing error on to a higher level.

You use catch when you want to handle the error (Exception).

Throwing the exception is an improvement over the older procedural way of handling errors where you would return error codes.

The reason it is better is because you can write your logic for the simple success case, and when things go wrong you simply throw an exception, no error handling in your lower level code.  It is then up to the higher levels of the application to decide what to do when a particular exception is throw.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, short and to the point of the subject. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

asawyer is right, you need to google and read up on error handling, it is a wide subject and you only really 'get it' after practice, talking, and reading about it. `throw` is something you probably won't need to use overly often, but you can occasionally use it to stop unwanted behaviour and create clearer errors for programmers using your methods. I know it is quite contrived but take this example:

```
public string WriteToFile(FileStream fs) {
  if (fs == null) {
    throw new ApplicationException("you passed a null filestream");
  }

  // write to file
}
```

You could just attempt to write the `FileStream` to a file without validating it, but in doing so you create a more understandable error for anyone consuming your method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `throw` keyword to throw an exception to the higher method.

Using this way, you can ocassionally make a better use of the exception, like closing database-access or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is effectively masking a lot of information that you could get from the exception.
what you regularly want to do is catch the exception, log the relevant information to some place where you can review it (logfile, db, eventlog) and then either throw(), which will keep you stack trace intact, or throw another "user friendly" exception which is masking the technical implementation.