# Better handling of exceptions occurring in methods connecting to internet

Tags: c#, exception, switch-statement

I have lots of methods which connects to internet to get something. So I need to handle the `WebException`s which can occur. But I would like to reduce try catch blocks in my code which uses these methods, because it looks ugly and difficult to look. What I'm doing right now is return a `Tuple` with an `enum` which I can use to see if the method failed or succeeded etc. Then I use a `switch` and `case` blocks to handle it. For example:

```
Tuple<GetIpReturn, string> ip = await _user.GetIp();
GetIpLocksReturn returnValue = ip.Item1;
switch (returnValue) {
    case GetIpLocksReturn.InternetError:
        // WebException occured
        break;
    case GetIpLocksReturn.AuthError:
        //
        break;
    case GetIpLocksReturn.Success:
        // Use ip.Item2 (The ip string)
        break;
}
```

But this also looks messy with those break statements.
Usually the error cases will have very few lines of code. Is there a better way of doing this? (Maybe using delegates?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, you should just let the exceptions happen. Wrapping exceptions in return values that include failure codes is antithetical to normal .NET idioms, requires more code in both caller and callee (including the added runtime cost of additional try/catch handling), and doesn't achieve anything that couldn't also be achieved using exceptions.

Converting exceptions to failure codes also *loses* potentially useful information, such as stack traces and `HRESULT` values.

Note that if you want to *add* information to exceptions, your implementation can catch exceptions that happen and then throw a new custom exception, for which you've provided the original exception as the `InnerException` property value.

For related discussion, see also:
[C# why throw errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9567727)
[Should my method throw its own exception, or let .NET throw if a file doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32951247)

They aren't exactly the same question, but they both include discussion on why exceptions are preferred in .NET code.

Comment: I tried this today and with custom exceptions and try catch, my code actually looks easier to read. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is regarding *handled* exceptions, meaning it happens enough and we know what to do about it; it's routine. In my application, for example, we simply show a message to the user in these well defined cases. Of course that depends on the application. I agree with Peter that unhandled exceptions should go into catches, not switches.

Just return a class that contains a) a friendly error message or blank, b) the data and c) the bool Success. The Status code and / or exception data you can put in there too for debugging. usually you just want to display or log the error message if not Success, and usually you just want use the data if Success = true. Success tells you if you can continue after the api call.

To sum up, OO to the rescue. Try to make the return class stronger so you can eliminate the switch based on what you know you eventually will do with these properties (e.g., display error message).

Comment: Yes. I only want the data only if `Success`. But I want to do other things based on the type of error which occured. The application should not terminate.